# Segmentation Fault: double free or corruption (fast top)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've a problem when I run this piece of code: a Segmentation Fault that appears during the `free` instruction of `percorso`. I cannot find the problem.

```
void ricerca(char nome[], struct node *radice, char percorso[], struct stringhe **indice) {
    struct node *punt = radice;     
    int dim = len(percorso);
    char *prov = NULL;
    if (dim > 0) {
        prov = malloc(2 * dim * sizeof(char));
        prov[0] = '\0';
        strcpy(prov, percorso);
        free(percorso);   //--------------------->here the SegFault
    }
    struct stringhe *nuovo = NULL;
    int i = 0, fine = 0;
    char *perc_orig = NULL;

    if (punt != NULL) {
        if (punt->array != NULL) {
            dim = len(prov) + len(punt->nome) + 2;
            percorso = malloc(dim * sizeof(char));
            percorso[0] = '\0';
            if (prov!=NULL)
                strcpy(percorso, prov);
            strcat(percorso, "/");
            strcat(percorso, punt->nome);
            perc_orig = malloc(dim * sizeof(char));
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                if (punt->array->vet[i] != NULL) {
                    perc_orig[0] = '\0';
                    strcpy(perc_orig, percorso);
                    ricerca(nome, punt->array->vet[i], perc_orig,indice);
                }
            }
            free(perc_orig);
        }

        if (strcmp(nome,punt->nome) == 0) {
            free(percorso);
            dim = len(prov) + len(punt->nome) + 2;
            percorso = malloc(dim * sizeof(char));
            inizializza(percorso, dim);
            if (prov != NULL)
                strcpy(percorso, prov);
            strcat(percorso, "/");
            strcat(percorso, punt->nome);
            nuovo = malloc(sizeof(struct stringhe));
            nuovo->next = NULL;
            nuovo->str = malloc(dim * sizeof(char));
            inizializza(nuovo->str, dim);
            strcpy(nuovo->str, percorso);

            nuovo->next = (*indice);
            *indice = nuovo;
        }           

        while (punt->chain != NULL && fine == 0) {
            ricerca(nome, punt->chain,prov, indice);
            fine = 1;
            if (prov!=NULL)
                free(prov);
        }           
    }       
}
```

The `len` function is like `strlen`, but the difference is that I've made it myself.

the context is:

```
void find(char nome[], struct node *radice) {
    char *perc = NULL;
    struct stringhe **inizio = NULL;
    inizio = malloc(sizeof(struct stringhe*));
    *inizio = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (radice->array->vet[i] != NULL) {
            perc = NULL;
            ricerca(nome, radice->array->vet[i], perc, inizio);
        }
    }
    if (*inizio != NULL) {
        insertion(inizio);
        stampap(*inizio);
    } else
        printf("no\n");
}
```

And the data structures:

```
struct tab {
    struct node *vet[64];
};

struct node {
    char nome[255];
    int num;
    int tipo;
    char *dati;
    struct tab *array;
    struct node *chain;
};
```

Comment: Is there a reason you made your own `len` function? And *where* in your code do the crash happen? Have you tried running in a debugger to catch the crash "in action"? Perhaps you should read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger?

Comment: Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, you don't tell us how you *call* the `ricerca` function, and what you are passing for `percorso`.

Comment: In which `free` do you get that error? Are you aware that you might call `free(percorso)` twice without allocating memory in between?

Comment: You need to debug this yourself. Or you may provide a [MCVE].

Comment: valgrind will probably point you right to the problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Got it! ricerca is recursive so we can indeed see how it is called.

Comment: You have to ensure that percorso, the original string is NON NULL and if it is non NULL, then it has to be NULL terminated string. For verifying that len function is same as strlen, you may add assert(dim == strlen(percorso))

Comment: regarding: `if (prov!=NULL)
                free(prov);`  the function: `free()` properly handles a NULL parameter, so no need to test the parameter first.

Comment: the OPs question is about a runtime problem.  BUT the OP did not supply run time code that we can use to expose the source of the problem.  Why should we debug this code?  To do so, we have to write the `main()` function AND supply dummy functions for those that are not present in the posted code.  As I see it, that is the OPs job to supply such code.

Comment: the `find()` function is using the variable `N`, which is not declared anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: the struct: `radice` is not defined anywhere in the posted code.   the struct: `stringhe` is not defined anywhere in the posted code.  The function: ricerca() doesn't have a prototype nor body.  The function: `insertion()` doesn't have a prototype nor body.  The function: `stampap()` doesn't have a prototype nor a body.  How do you expect us to determine what is wrong with your code if we cannot compile the code and certainly cannot experience the seg fault for ourselves?

Comment: regarding: `prov = malloc(2 * dim * sizeof(char));`  1) the expression `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1.  using that expression in a call to `malloc()` just clutters the code and does not add any useful information.  2)  when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: what is the function: `len()`?  given the surrounding code, I suspect the code should have called `strlen()` from the `string.h` header file.

Comment: was the parameter: `percorso` generated via a call to one of the heap allocation functions?  If not, then that is the source of the problem.  We cannot tell due so very much necessary code is missing.

Comment: the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) expect the length parameter to be of type: `size_t` not `int`  however, most of the calls to `malloc()` are using the variable: `dim` which is an `int`

Answer (score 1):

This is really weird:

```
if (some condition)
   free(percorso);
```

Later on we have:

```
    perc_orig = malloc(dim*sizeof(char));
    for(something){
        if(something){
            ricerca(nome,punt->array->vet[i],perc_orig,indice);
        }
    }
    free(perc_orig);
```

If that if conditions happens, perc_orig will be freed twice. Kaboom.

I think your problem is you think that `ricerca(..., char percico[], ...)` copies percico. It doesn't; it's really `ricerca(..., char *percico, ...)` so you ended up freeing the memory twice.

Comment: I know that, but I do those free for decrease garbage.

Comment: @AlessioFiorentino: It's freeing memory owned somewhere else.

Comment: When i debug the code, i see that the first node of the chain has this problem. So if i check the content of that string i see the is not empty but with the next free istruction i've the "double free error".

Answer (score 0):

the sizing for the char arrays needs to allow for the trailing NUL ('\0') character.

ALL fields that are referenced by `strcpy()` and similar functions need to have ALL source character arrays NUL terminated.

The code does not seem to be allocating enough room for those trailing NUL bytes NOR terminating every character array with a NUL char.

Answer (score -2):

Segmentation fault occurs when you initialize a character pointer to `NULL` and try to point it to a not null value 
For example,

```
char *a=NULL;
a='a';
```

Will cause segmentation fault. To avoid this you can try to initialize as,

```
char *a;
a='a';
```

Comment: The segmentation fault occurs when you dereference a badly initialized pointer. Putting the value `97` (`'a'`) in the pointer `a` will cause an undefined behaviour (probably a crash) when you'll use `*a` : because of  an attempt to memory location 97

Comment: what if the undefined behavior turned out to be segmentation fault in this case?